# PHP Excel download with refresh page

Tags: php, excel, export, codeigniter-4, phpspreadsheet

I have an Excel export function in CodeIgniter 4, here is the code in my controller:

```
    public function exportLembur()
    {
        $dataLembur = $this->ExportModel->getAllDataOvertime();
        $writer = $this->export(null, $dataLembur, 'allLembur');
        // return dd($dataLembur);

        $fileName = date('Y-m-d-His') . '.xlsx';
        $file = $writer->save($fileName);

        return $this->response->download($fileName, $file, true)->setFileName($fileName);
    }
```

that function runs fine, then I try to create ajax javascript to refresh the page when the function works like this:
`$(document).on('submit', '#download-all', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

```
// Reference to the form
var $form = $(this);
console.log($form)

// Perform an AJAX request to trigger the download
$.ajax({
  url: "<?= base_url('DownloadController/exportLembur') ?>",
  method: $form.attr('method'),
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
});
```

});`

Why when I use that JavaScript codes, the Excel is successfully exported in the cache but not exported in the download browser?

Comment: _Because_ you are making a background request. You can not directly trigger a download dialog when using AJAX/fetch.

Comment: Why do i an ajax anyway if you reload the page afterwards?

Comment: a common approach to handle file downloads with AJAX is to create a hidden iframe to which you set the download URL

Comment: @SimonWeber I want to refresh the page after download, is there anything else I can do?